# Unable to use variable in JS forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to check wether a property already exists in the `otherFeatures` array. I am checking this with the `match` variable. When I console log the results out inside `match` it works correctly but when I try use it in the if statement it always returns `undefined`

```
const otherFeatures = [
  {heading: "Taps", value: "Silver"},
  {heading: "Taps", value: "Bronze"},
  {heading: "Sink", value: "Ceramic"},
];

let features = [];

const featuresCheck = otherFeatures.forEach((item, index) => {
  const match = features.forEach((feat) => {
    return feat.heading === item.heading;
  });
  console.log("match", match);
  if (match) {
    console.log('match true'); 
  } else {
    features[index] = item;
  }
});
```

Comment: change `const match = features.forEach((feat) => {` to `const match = features.some((feat) => {`

Comment: It does no good to return in a `.forEach` loop. You'll want to use a regular loop, so you can `break;` out of it, or `.find`, anyways, so your loop doesn't continue. But.. there's nothing in your `features` Array in the first place. Why would you need the inner loop if you're testing `otherFeatures`? You're not making sense.

Comment: @StackSlave the `features` array is where I am going to store the unique objects from `otherFeatures` I need to check against this because I am pushing to it. If you have a better way to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach()` doesn't return the result of the callback function. If you want that, you need to use `map()`. Since `forEach()` doesn't return a useful value, there's no point in assigning it to a variable.

```js
const otherFeatures = [
  {heading: "Taps", value: "Silver"},
  {heading: "Taps", value: "Bronze"},
  {heading: "Sink", value: "Ceramic"},
];

let features = [];

otherFeatures.forEach((item, index) => {
  const match = features.map((feat) => {
    return feat.heading === item.heading;
  });
  console.log("match", match);
  if (match) {
    console.log('match true'); 
  } else {
    features[index] = item;
  }
});
console.log("features", features);
```

However, all arrays are considered truthy in JavaScript, even if they're empty, so `if (match)` will always succeed. If you want to know if any of the elements match, you should use `some()`.

```js
const otherFeatures = [
  {heading: "Taps", value: "Silver"},
  {heading: "Taps", value: "Bronze"},
  {heading: "Sink", value: "Ceramic"},
];

let features = [];

otherFeatures.forEach((item, index) => {
  const match = features.some((feat) => {
    return feat.heading === item.heading;
  });
  console.log("match", match);
  if (match) {
    console.log('match true'); 
  } else {
    features[index] = item;
  }
});
console.log("features", features);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that helps a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the last comma in your Array of Objects.

Comment: @StackSlave JavaScript allows extra commas at the end of arrays and objects.

Comment: Trailing commas are not allowed in JSON, so it's a bad practice.

Comment: Neither are object keys without quotes, but I'm not going to start quoting my keys, either.